# Error: Compile Error: Expression cannot be assigned at line 17 column 13

Tags: apex

getting the compiler error while accessing the field either from fieldset member or from custom setting. below is the code. Please help me how to access the field from contact

```
webservice static String createWellnessRecord(Id ldId)
    {
        Lead ld = new AP13_CreateWellnessContact().getLeadDetails(ldId);
        List<Contact> lsContact = new List<Contact>();
        Map<String, LeadToContact__c> allRecords = LeadToContact__c.getAll(); 
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : new AP13_CreateWellnessContact().getLeadDemographicFields()){
            Contact con = new Contact();
            String apiName = allRecords.get(f.getFieldPath()).Contact_API_Name__c;
            con+'.'+apiName = (String)ld.get(f.getFieldPath()) ;//Error is here
                    lsContact.add(con);
                    System.debug('list::::'+lsContact);
        }
        insert lsContact;

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here `con+'.'+apiName`?

Comment: My requirement is, i need to create a contact record when user clicks on the button from lead, while creating i need to copy some lead demographic values to contact ( Fields and API names are same for Lead and Contact). That time, i have tried with fieldset member but it is not working so i have created a custom setting which contains lead api name and contact api name. Now i have created a contact object inside for loop and am accessing the contact api name based on lead fieldset member from custom setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to access SObject fields by name, you need to use both the [get](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get) and [put](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put) methods. So the line should look more like this:

```
con.put(apiName, (String) ld.get(f.getFieldPath()));
```